# Changing compiler in Qt

Tags: qt, gcc

How to change compiler (GCC) in Qt? I've installed GCC 4.4 and 4.6. At the momment Qt uses 4.4 but I'd like it to use 4.6. How to do it?

Comment: How comes it uses one? It compiles with whatever compiler you provide... Or do you mean Qt binary distribution for Windows with its own mingw instance?

Comment: @vines yes, mingw at the moment but I'd like to use GCC 4.6

Answer (score 20):

In the build sequence it may have a `qmake` command like `qmake YourProject.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64` the choice of the tool chain is done in the `spec` file here `linux-g++-64`. Your will find this file in `path-to-the-sdk/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++-64` (you get the concept right?)... If you open the spec file you will see that it includes the `linux` spec and the `g++` spec.

One solution is to copy the `g++` spec file and rename it `g++-4.6` for example edit it and change :

```
QMAKE_CC = gcc
QMAKE_CXX = g++
```

to :

```
QMAKE_CC = gcc-4.6 
QMAKE_CXX = g++-4.6
```

Idem for the  `linux-g++-64` it can be copied to `linux-g++-4.6-64` and modify the `include(...)` command to include your new `g++-4.6` file.

Finally build your project with `qmake YourProject.pro -r -spec linux-g++-4.6-64`.

I hope it's clear :) ...

Answer (score 10):

I realise I am **very** late for the party but on Linux it is as simple as follows:

```
qmake -makefile <your-project.pro> -spec linux-clang
```

On my system, all sorts of different `mkspecs` are available at:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs`

Answer (score 8):

Running `make CC=my-custom-gcc CXX=my-custom-g++ LINK=my-custom-g++` seems to do the trick for me. But it might not be 100% safe (i.e. I wouldn't be surprised if running qmake with Linux specs and then specifying mingw32 compilers would fail).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Qt Creator 2.2.0, you can try `Tools > Options > Tool Chains` and then `Add > MinGW`.

Comment: I did that but it seems to be still using the previous version. There is no option to remove the previous conf.